# List of product categories to a dict of product categories

Tags: python

I would like to create a product category representation as a python dictionary.
The input is the following list of product categories, represented as list of lists:

```
categories_list = [
    ['computer', 'laptop'],
    ['computer', 'desktop'],
    ['computer', 'processor', 'Intel'],
    ['computer', 'processor', 'AMD'],
    ['computer', 'accessories', 'mouse'],
    ['computer', 'accessories', 'keyboard'],
    ['controller', 'raspberryPI'],
    ['controller', 'Arduino'],
    ['controller', 'accessories'],
    ['other'],
    ['electronics', 'other']
]
```

I would like to turn the list into a dictionary like this:

```
categories_dict = {
    'computer': {'laptop': None, 
                 'desktop': None, 
                 'processor': {'Intel': None, 
                               'AMD': None}, 
                 'accessories': {'mouse': None, 
                                 'keyboard': None}},
    'controller': {'raspberryPI': None, 
                   'Arduino': None, 
                   'accessories': None},
    'other': None,
    'electronics': {'other': None}
}
```

This represents the hierarchy. The main levels are: computer, controller, other, electronics.

Some of these have children, and some of those children have also their children.
For example the computers children are:
**laptop, desktop, processor, accessories**
-the processor and accessories have also subchildren:
**Intel, AMD** - for processor
**mouse, keyboard** - for accessories

None indicates that there are no further children/subcategories.

My code so far creates some tree structure, but this is still not what I need.

```
def create_cat_dict():
    dict_tree = {}
    main_name = ""
    for cat_list in all_categories:
        for index, cat_name in enumerate(cat_list):
            if index == 0 and cat_name not in dict_tree:
                main_name = cat_name
                dict_tree[cat_name] = {}
            if index > 0 and cat_name not in dict_tree[main_name].keys():
                dict_tree[main_name][cat_name] = None

    print(dict_tree)
```

It creates this dictionary, which is still not correct:

```
{'computer': {'AMD': None,
              'Intel': None,
              'accessories': None,
              'desktop': None,
              'keyboard': None,
              'laptop': None,
              'mouse': None,
              'processor': None},
 'controller': {'Arduino': None,
                'accessories': None,
                'raspberryPI': None},
 'electronics': {'other': None},
 'other': {}}
```

Under **computer>processor should be {'Intel': None, 'AMD': None}** 
Under **computer>accessories should be {'mouse': None, 'keyboard': None}**

I would like to ask for help on how to read all the categories, even if a category level is 4, 5, 6 level deep.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `dict.setdefault`:

```
def nest(d, keys, value=None):
    for k in keys[:-1]:
        d = d.setdefault(k, {})
    d[keys[-1]] = value

res = {}
for l in categories_list:
    nest(res, l)
```

Output:

```
{'computer': {'accessories': {'keyboard': None, 'mouse': None},
              'desktop': None,
              'laptop': None,
              'processor': {'AMD': None, 'Intel': None}},
 'controller': {'Arduino': None, 'accessories': None, 'raspberryPI': None},
 'electronics': {'other': None},
 'other': None}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works, but not always. For example I've added a new category:
['other', 'sub other']
After this it results in an error.

Comment: What would be the expected output for that?

Comment: For example for these two rows:
['other'],
['other', 'sub other']
It should return:
'other': {'sub other': None}}

Comment: But you already helped a much, so I am going to figure it out myself. I have upvoted your answer as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

iv'e updated the answer of [Sam Prince Franklin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14581989/sam-prince-franklin) to replace the empty dict {} with None:

```py
categories_list = [
    ['computer', 'laptop'],
    ['computer', 'desktop'],
    ['computer', 'processor', 'Intel'],
    ['computer', 'processor', 'AMD'],
    ['computer', 'accessories', 'mouse'],
    ['computer', 'accessories', 'keyboard'],
    ['controller', 'raspberryPI'],
    ['controller', 'Arduino'],
    ['controller', 'accessories'],
    ['other'],
    ['electronics', 'other'],
    ['other', 'sub other'],
] 

def create_cat_dict(categories_list):
    # Initialize an empty dictionary
    categories_dict = {}

    # Iterate over the list of categories
    for cat_list in categories_list:
        # Initialize a reference to the current level in the dictionary
        current_level = categories_dict

        # Iterate over the items in the category list
        for cat_name in cat_list:
            # If the category name is not in the current level, add it, 
            # or if it is None and it has subcategory, replace None with {}
            if cat_name not in current_level or current_level[cat_name] is None:
                current_level[cat_name] = {}
            # replace empty dict {} with None
            if cat_name == cat_list[-1]: 
                current_level[cat_name] = None

            # if not current_level[cat_name] and cat_name in current_level:
            #     current_level[cat_name] = {}
            
            # Update the reference to the current level
            current_level = current_level[cat_name]
            

    # Return the dictionary representing the hierarchy of product categories
    return categories_dict
```

and the result is like the following:

```
{
    'computer': 
    {
        'laptop': None,
        'desktop': None, 
        'processor': {
                    'Intel': None,
                    'AMD': None
                    },
        'accessories': {
                    'mouse': None,
                    'keyboard': None
                }
    },
    'controller': 
        {
            'raspberryPI': None,
             'Arduino': None,
            'accessories': None
        },
    'other': {'sub other': None},
    'electronics': {'other': None}
}
```

Comment: It has the same problem as Chris answer. Works with the category list above. But as soon as I gave it another category: ['other', 'sub other'] - it results in an error:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: But still thanks for answer!

Comment: you are welcome @AttilaToth , i have updated the answer and fixed the problem.

Comment: Sam Prince Franklin has no post or answer in StackOverFlow

Comment: @furkanayd Apparently he deleted his answer, he wrote the first answer and deleted it.